# Is it possible to upload dSYM to Crashlytics under the Windows Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, crashlytics

I make an iOS App in Xamarin.iOS in Windows Microsoft Visual Studio.
How to upload dSYM files to Crashlytics either manually or automatically?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If you're building on Windows, using Fastlane to upload the dSYMs to us is the recommended path. The lane would be:

```
lane :refresh_dsyms do
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics   # Upload them to Crashlytics
  clean_build_artifacts           # Delete the local dSYM files
end
```

And the command would be:

```
   $ fastlane refresh_dsyms
```

You would need to configure your fastlane to provide the dSYM path.

Comment: I know nothing about Mac. All my life I've been coding in Windows. What is lane means? Is it a file? Where is it placed? Can you expand your answer to cover some details?

Comment: A lane is a system of commands to run in Fastlane. I'd recommend looking here: https://krausefx.com/blog/download-dsym-symbolication-files-from-itunes-connect-for-bitcode-ios-apps

Comment: Well, I've read it, thank you. But how does fastlane have access to project files while they are located on Windows?

Comment: You would need to provide the path to Fastlane where your dSYMs are located after building via Xamarin. You will also need Ruby installed on your Windows machine.